# Extracting slopes for cases from a mixed effects model (lme4)

Tags: r, mixed-model

I would like to extract the slopes for each individual in a mixed effect model, as outlined in the following paragraph

> Mixed effects models were used to characterize individual paths of change in the cognitive summary measures, including terms for age, sex, and years of education as fixed effects (Laird and Ware, 1982; Wilson et al., 2000, 2002c).... Residual, individual cognitive decline slope terms were extracted from the mixed models, after adjustment for the effects of age, sex, and education. Person-specific, adjusted residual slopes were then used as a quantitative outcome phenotype for the genetic association analyses. These estimates equate to the difference between an individual’s slope and the predicted slope of an individual of the same age, sex, and education level.
>
> De Jager, P. L., Shulman, J. M., Chibnik, L. B., Keenan, B. T., Raj, T., Wilson, R. S., et al. (2012). [A genome-wide scan for common variants affecting the rate of age-related cognitive decline](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22054870). Neurobiology of Aging, 33(5), 1017.e1–1017.e15.

I have looked at using the `coef` function to extract the coefficients for each individual, but I am unsure if this is the correct approach to be using.

Can anyone provide some advice on how to do this?

```
#example R code 
library(lme4)
attach(sleepstudy)  
fml <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
beta <- coef(fml)$Subject
colnames(beta) <- c("Intercept", "Slope")
beta

summary(beta)
summary(fm1)
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The model:

```
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

---

The function `coef` is the right approach for extracting individual
differences.

```
> coef(fm1)$Subject
    (Intercept)       Days
308    253.6637 19.6662581
309    211.0065  1.8475834
310    212.4449  5.0184067
330    275.0956  5.6529540
331    273.6653  7.3973908
332    260.4446 10.1951151
333    268.2455 10.2436611
334    244.1725 11.5418622
335    251.0714 -0.2848735
337    286.2955 19.0955694
349    226.1950 11.6407008
350    238.3351 17.0814915
351    255.9829  7.4520286
352    272.2687 14.0032989
369    254.6806 11.3395025
370    225.7922 15.2897513
371    252.2121  9.4791308
372    263.7196 11.7513155
```

These values are a combination of the fixed effects and the variance components
(random effects). You can use `summary` and `coef` to obtain the coefficients
of the fixed effects.

```
> coef(summary(fm1))[ , "Estimate"]
(Intercept)        Days 
  251.40510    10.46729
```

The intercept is 251.4 and the slope (associated with `Days`) is 10.4. 
These coeffcients are the mean of all subjects. To obtain the random effects,
you can use `ranef`.

```
> ranef(fm1)$Subject
    (Intercept)        Days
308   2.2585637   9.1989722
309 -40.3985802  -8.6197026
310 -38.9602496  -5.4488792
330  23.6905025  -4.8143320
331  22.2602062  -3.0698952
332   9.0395271  -0.2721709
333  16.8404333  -0.2236248
334  -7.2325803   1.0745763
335  -0.3336936 -10.7521594
337  34.8903534   8.6282835
349 -25.2101138   1.1734148
350 -13.0699598   6.6142055
351   4.5778364  -3.0152574
352  20.8635944   3.5360130
369   3.2754532   0.8722166
370 -25.6128737   4.8224653
371   0.8070401  -0.9881551
372  12.3145406   1.2840295
```

These values are the variance components of the subjects. Every row 
corresponds to one subject. Inherently the mean of each column is zero since
the values correspond to the differences in relation to the fixed effects.

```
> colMeans(ranef(fm1)$Subject)
  (Intercept)          Days 
 4.092529e-13 -2.000283e-13
```

Note that these values are equal to zero, deviations are due to imprecision
of floating point number representation.

The result of `coef(fm1)$Subject` incoporates the fixed effects into
the random effects, i.e., the fixed effect coefficients are added to
the random effects. The results are individual intercepts and slopes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that cleared up how the individual coefficients are calculated. One further question though, when the above paragraph stated that they adjusted for residuals is this the same as including the random effects in the coefficients or is that a separate issue?

Comment: You state that coef(summary(fm1))[, "Estimate"] produces the mean of all subjects. I take that to imply the intercept is the mean value of "Reaction", but 'mean(sleepstudy$Reaction) = 298.5079' . This is the interpretation of the intercept in a linear regression and I'm trying to understand the coefficients in mixed effects models and am struggling to get things (like this to add up). Why isn't the intercept 298.5?

Comment: @svannoy Note that the intercept is the *estimated* value of the dependent variable when all covariates are equal to zero. Here, `Days` is not centered at the mean, and therefore the intercept of the model is lower than the mean value of `Reaction`. Furthermore, the regression line is the best linear fit. Hence, the observations are not necessarily on this line.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein thanks, for clarifying that. Is it accurate then to say that in OLS regression with just a single categorical predictor variable and deviation coding (contr.sum()) the intercept is precisely the grand mean; whereas in RC regression with a random intercept model the intercept is the estimated grand mean?

Comment: @svannoy Yes, with deviation coding the intercept reflects the Grand Mean in OLS regression. In a linear mixed model, the intercept is indeed the estimated Grand Mean.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein "These values are the variance components of the subjects." How is it then possible to get "negative" variance components?

Comment: @M.Beausoleil The different values for the levels of the random factor can be negative because they are derived from the estimated distribution with zero mean and nonnegative variance.

Comment: OK! Sure totally make sense. The variance estimated is nonnegative, but the *values* pulled from the distribution of random effects which is centred at 0 can be positive or negative (falling from each side of the mean = 0). Make total sense. I was just misinterpreting the sentence. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @M.Beausoleil Thanks for the feedback.Your description is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old question, but this may be useful (at least for later me anyway) - you can use `ranef()` and `fixef()` from `lme4` and this is less verbose than the previous answer.

```
> ranef(fm1)
$Subject
    (Intercept)        Days
308   2.2585509   9.1989758
309 -40.3987381  -8.6196806
310 -38.9604090  -5.4488565
330  23.6906196  -4.8143503
331  22.2603126  -3.0699116
332   9.0395679  -0.2721770
333  16.8405086  -0.2236361
334  -7.2326151   1.0745816
335  -0.3336684 -10.7521652
337  34.8904868   8.6282652
349 -25.2102286   1.1734322
350 -13.0700342   6.6142178
351   4.5778642  -3.0152621
352  20.8636782   3.5360011
369   3.2754656   0.8722149
370 -25.6129993   4.8224850
371   0.8070461  -0.9881562
372  12.3145921   1.2840221

with conditional variances for “Subject” 
> fixef(fm1)
(Intercept)        Days 
  251.40510    10.46729
```