# Interpreting slopes for individual cases in a generalized linear mixed-effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model

Similar to a previous poster ([Extracting slopes for cases from a mixed effects model (lme4)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122009/extracting-slopes-for-cases-from-a-mixed-effects-model-lme4/122018)), I am interested in extracting slopes for individual cases (individuals) using a mixed-effects model (lme4 package). I am running a generalized linear mixed-effects model using a binomial distribution, predicting a binary outcome based on a single continuous predictor. I have used the function `coef` to extract individual differences using the method recommended in the previous post, i.e. `coef(model)$Subject` and am noticing that the estimates I get do not always seem to align with my data itself. For example, for one subject their mean level of the predictor variable for the case where DV = 1 is -0.227 and when DV = 0, the mean level of the predictor is equal to -0.04. I would expect, then, that this subject would have a negative coefficient since the odds of the outcome being 1 should be lower when the level of the predictor is more positive. However, this subject actually has a positive coefficient (2.20). A number of subjects in my dataset seem to show this inconsistency.

I am wondering if anyone can provide an explanation or advice as to why the individual subject coefficients from a binomial GLMM might not always be consistent with the mean value of the predictor variable for a given subject for each possible outcome (0 or 1). I am wondering if I have misspecified my model or whether I am just not conceptually understanding the interpretation of the coefficient, which I assumed reflects the change to the log-odds of outcome = 1 associated with a 1-unit increase in the predictor.

Here is my model specification: 
`mod1 <- glmer(Y ~ X.scaled + (X.scaled | ID),              data=x,family=binomial,na.action="na.omit",glmerControl(optimizer="optimx",optCtrl=list(method=c("nlminb","bobyqa"))))`

I would appreciate any advice on this matter!